# Android Room Conditional Query for IN and NULL

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have complex Android Room Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE (:applyAssigneeFilters IS 0 OR assigneeMemberId IN(:assigneeFilters))...
```

I am passing `boolean` - `applyAssigneeFilters` to determine if query should return items where `assigneeMemberId` is in `assigneeFilters` list.

This works pretty well but, now I have new requirement to include items which are unassigned.

I would like to have similar option (`bool` value) which will filter items by `assigneeMemberId` **and/or** `isAssigneed`. Both options can be combined.

Edit:

On the UI side I have list with options:

```
[] Unassigned
[] Member1
[] Member2
```

Before adding "Unassigned" option `applyAssigneeFilters` variable was just a `assigneeFilters.isEmpty()` check. After added `Unassigned` I need to filter only `Unassigned` items or/and these which assigned member is in `assigneeFilters`.

Examples:
Given items:

```
Item(id: 1, memberId: 1, unassigned: false)
Item(id: 2, memberId: 2, unassigned: false)
Item(id: 3, memberId: null, unassigned: true)
```

and options

```
[X] Unassigned
[] Member1
[] Member2
```

result will be:

```
Item(id: 3, memberId: null, unassigned: true)
```

For options:

```
[X] Unassigned
[] Member1
[X] Member2
```

result will be:

```
Item(id: 2, memberId: 2, unassigned: false)
Item(id: 3, memberId: null, unassigned: true)
```

For options:

```
[] Unassigned
[X] Member1
[X] Member2
```

result will be:

```
Item(id: 1, memberId: 1, unassigned: false)
Item(id: 2, memberId: 2, unassigned: false)
```

Comment: Post sample data an expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas Added few examples describing how my query should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found soulution for my own problem.

```
(:applyAssigneeFilters IS 0 OR (assigneeMemberId IN(:assigneeFilters) OR (:unassignedMemberId IN(:assigneeFilters) AND hasAssignee IS 0)))
```

So I introduced `unassignedMemberId` which is added to `assigneeFilters` list and model had already field `hasAssignee` which allowed me to filter items without assignee and still use `applyAssigneeFilters` flag.

Answer (score 0):

based upon your examples then you could simply use:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Model WHERE unassigned=:applyAssigneeFilters OR memberId IN(:assigneeFilters);")
    fun getModelsByFilter(applyAssigneeFilters: Boolean, assigneeFilters: List<Long>): List<Model>
```

- this does assume that false and true or actually stored as 0 and NOT 0 rather than the textual values, as would appear to the the case when you are comparing 0 in the SQL you have provided.

Here's a Working example that produces the results:-

The Database Stuff used:-

```
@Entity
data class Model(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null,
    var memberId: Long?,
    var unassigned: Boolean
)
@Database(entities = [Model::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(model: Model)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Model WHERE unassigned=:applyAssigneeFilters OR memberId IN(:assigneeFilters);")
    fun getModelsByFilter(applyAssigneeFilters: Boolean, assigneeFilters: List<Long>): List<Model>
}
```

A layout for the activity which has 3 checkboxes (unassigned, member 1 and member 2) a Button to **GO** and get the results and a TextView in which to display the results:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/unassigned"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unassigned" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/member1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Member1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/member2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Member2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO"
        >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultant_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "500dp"
        >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    lateinit var unassigned: CheckBox
    lateinit var member1: CheckBox
    lateinit var member2: CheckBox
    lateinit var goButton: Button
    lateinit var resultantData: TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        unassigned = this.findViewById(R.id.unassigned)
        member1 = this.findViewById(R.id.member1)
        member2 = this.findViewById(R.id.member2)
        goButton = this.findViewById(R.id.go)
        resultantData = this.findViewById(R.id.resultant_data)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.insert(Model(1,1,false))
        dao.insert(Model(2,2,false))
        dao.insert(Model(3,null,true))

        goButton.setOnClickListener { doit()}


    }

    fun doit() {
        val assigneeFilter = ArrayList<Long>()
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        if (member1.isChecked) assigneeFilter.add(1)
        if (member2.isChecked) assigneeFilter.add(2)
        for(m in dao.getModelsByFilter(unassigned.isChecked,assigneeFilter)) {
            if (sb.length > 0) sb.append("\n")
            sb.append("ID=${m.id} MEMBERID=${m.memberId} UNASSIGNED=${m.unassigned}")
        }
        resultantData.text = sb
    }
}
```

**Results:-**

When **first run** (nothing shown):-

[image]

If Go is then clicked (**nothing checked** i.e. all unassigned, same result as 3rd example (is this what you want?)) :-

[image]

Checkboxes as per **first example**:-

[image]

Checkboxes as per **second example**:-

[image]

Checkboxes as per **third example**:-

[image]

The data in the database (via App Inspection):-

[image]

Comment: Hey @mikeT, thanks for the whole solution. It seems that it is not working correctly. In example check only Member1 - it will return Member1 and Member2. For all cleared checkboxes, I will get only Member1 and Member2 (no Unassigned).